# Excel Transpose With Column Grouping

Tags: excel, powerquery, transpose, unpivot

```
visit_id                            | cooler_door_target | Yeni Sampling.cooler_door_target

77152a75-8063-4edc-9502-d11c2cf94afd|                  10|   10
ef04cf76-b54e-4837-a253-4e0677650a42|                  15|   15
```

I have above data that I want to reformat as

```
                     Visit                               | Yeni Sampling| Engine
cooler_door_target   77152a75-8063-4edc-9502-d11c2cf94afd|        10    |       10
```

I have tried transpose, but it puts everything in rows. The closest I got was unpivot and transpose, but I still can't find a way to group all Engine. columns (the ones that don't have any leading tag, and Yeni Sampling. columns.

Comment: Please post sample data as copiable text along with expected output. Thanks

Comment: 1) Please provide data as code/file, not just screenshot
2) you can add 2nd screenshot as picture to the post body, no need for external link

Comment: Did this solution work for you? If so please mark question as solved by toggling checkmark on answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this, then sort as needed. Based on original question before change

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"project_id", "visit_id"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"."}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Attribute.1", type text}, {"Attribute.2", type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type1", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type1"[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value", List.Sum)
in     #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]